# What is the solution for 'For fetch only' in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, performance, syntax, db2, migration

I have one query in DB2 which use 'for fetch only' but I need to convert it into postgresql. What can we use it for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that in PostgreSQL. In PostgreSQL, any cursor can be used for a positioned `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Just omit the clause in PostgreSQL.